# nsstring in objective c

Tags: objective-c

i am a beginer in objective c.i found the following line in code and is not able to understand what it does it do, as storeselect has not been used anywhere in the code.

NSString *storeSelect=@"";

Comment: Is storeSelect used afterwords?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`storeSelect` is the name of a variable whose type is `NSString *`, with the value assigned to `@""`

Answer (score 2):

Objective-C builds on C language. In C, quotes are placed around string literals, i.e. "hello". To distinguish NSString and C strings (char pointers, `char *`), Objective-C uses `@` in front of strings, so `@""` is simply empty `NSString`. If there was no `@`, it would be empty C string, e.g. `char *myString = "hello world";`.

Answer (score 1):

It's just assigning an empty string to a variable named `storeSelect`. The `@""` is for constant strings.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *storeSelect=@"Hello World";
```

is a shortcut of -

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithCString:"Hello World"];
```

as "stringWithCString" is convenience method it will be automatically adds autoreleased.

Comment: `stringWithCString:` is deprecated in favor of `stringWithCString:encoding:`